# How print syntax tree using Javac

Tags: java, compiler-construction, javac, static-analysis

I implemented a program [TreeScanner](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/javac/tree/com/sun/source/util/TreeScanner.html#scan(java.lang.Iterable,%20P)), to print information about all nodes in AST. The program supports all types (all visit methods are implemented). However, the problem is that for the statement, `System.out.println(object.YYY);` the program does not visit field reference **YYY**.

It detects **object** as identifier, but can not detect **YYY** as identifier. However, when I have System.out.println(YYY); then visitIdentifier will visit **YYY**.

Please let me know what is the difference between the both above lines, while in one YYY is visited by visitidentifier, in the another case it is not visited.

How can I visit **YYY** in **object.YYY**?

In class org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom we have [FieldAccess](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fjdt%2Fcore%2Fdom%2FASTVisitor.html) which is called in both above cases for **YYY**, but seems TreeScanner in Javac has no similar method.

Comment: It might help to post some code...

Comment: Is `YYY` a `static final` (i.e. constant) field?

Comment: I checked all these cases: static, static final, and normal field. In all three cases it could not detect YYY as identifier.

Comment: Odd. If it was a constant, it might be an optimization where javac returns the value of the constant. But if it always happens ...

Comment: Can you post a working example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `visitIdentifier` method gets called on Identifier notes in the AST, which are created when an identifier is used as an expression. However the syntax for member selection in Java is `<expression>.<identifier>`, not `<expression>.<expression>`, meaning the `YYY` in `object.YYY` is not a sub-expression and thus doesn't get its own subtree. Instead the `MemberSelectTree` for `object.YYY` simply contains `YYY` as a `Name` directly, accessible via `getIdentifier()`. There is no `visitName` method in `TreeScanner`, so the only way to get at `YYY` here would be to do so from `visitMemberSelect` directly.

Here's how you'd print `object.YYY` using `visitMemberSelect`:

```
Void visitMemberSelect(MemberSelectTree memberSelect, Void p) {
    // Print the object
    memberSelect.getExpression().accept(this, p);
    System.out.print(".");
    // Print the name of the member
    System.out.print(memberSelect.getIdentifier());
}
```